# .click() functionality when clicking elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

Basically i want to click on a tab and a drop down menu appears then when you re-click the same tab or any of the others I want it to hide that tab/show the other tab if clicked on the same/other tab.

I tried

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.sub-nav-list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

and tried

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.sub-nav-list').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.sub-nav-list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

but cant work it out! any insight? Thanks

html:

```
<nav class="secondary-nav">
    <ul class="list clearfix">
        <li class="leaders click">Leadership <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
            <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Board of Directors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact click">Contact Info <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
            <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                <li><a href="">Email Notification</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Information Request</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="docs click">Documents <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
            <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                <li><a href="">Governance Documents</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Press Release</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Reports &amp; Presentations</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sec Filings</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Frenquently Asked Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Tax Information</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li class="research click">Research <span class="arrow">&gt;</span>
            <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                <li><a href="">Dividends and Distributions</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Stock Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Analyst Coverage</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Market Makers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you show your html? do you really have .sub-nav-list within your element that you click (.click)?

Comment: can you post your html-structure too?

Comment: A jsfiddle demo of what you have so far would be quite helpful.

Comment: Is the element with .sub-nav-list really a child of .click?

Comment: ok html posted above

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two possible issues there.

1) `sub-nav-list` is not a children of `click` element. If they are on the same level something like that might work:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-nav-list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

2) You have these elements generated dynamically - so you need use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with selector of any parent element that exists before you dynamically generate your sub-menus (let say `nav-list`):

```
$(".click").on("click", ".nav-list", function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.sub-nav-list').toggleClass('active');
});
```